# ASUS G53SW fans spinning at full speed

Tags: laptop, motherboard, gpu, fan

My Asus G53SW laptop had a video output problem which I narrowed down to a GPU failure. 
Took it apart, reflowed the GPU with a hot air desoldering station, applied new paste, cleaned the fans and assembled again.

Laptop boots and works no problem, CPU and GPU idle temps are ~35 yet both fans spin constantly on full speed and are very loud, even at no load or in BIOS. 
There is a single connector on each fan and I'm 100% sure I connected them, sensors must also be connected since I can see the temps in conky.
Since the assembly of this one is a long and painfull process, due to multiple ribbon & teethed clamp connectors is there anything else I should check?